# Is it possible to disallow writes to a sshfs mountpoint?

Tags: permissions, mount, sshfs

Is it possible to disallow remote servers from writing to a sshfs mounted folder, either on server or client side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the permissions of the folder so that there are no permissions for the SSH user used when mounting the directory to write to that directory.

Comment: I don't think this will have an effect on the root user of the client side?

Comment: The SSH connection always uses the rights of the user on the server side of the connection. It does not matter which user is used on the client side to connect to the other end.